# Android scale animation using incorrect coordinates

Tags: java, android, scaleanimation

I'm trying to scale an `ImageButton` from 100% to 0%. That part is working but it also seems to be moving the view toward the top left corner of the screen (towards 0, 0). I don't want that I just want to scale it. Why is this also translating the view?

> The ScaleAnimation implementation

```
  if (view.getVisibility() == 0) {
        final ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, centerX, Animation.ABSOLUTE, centerY);
        scaleAnimation.setInterpolator(interpolator);

    scaleAnimation.setDuration(5000);
            view.startAnimation((Animation)scaleAnimation);

        scaleAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    view.setVisibility(n);
                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }

                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }
            });
    }
}
```

The `ImageButton` and its parent `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` in XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/main_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/buttonToggleResultsWindow0"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:hint="Hide results window"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_filter_tilt_shift_white_24dp"
    android:onClick="toggleResultsWindow"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_circle"
/>
```

**Edit 1**

If I change the `ScaleAnimation` constructor to this

```
final ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, centerX, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, centerY);
```

And set `centerX` to 8 and `centerY` to 4 it seems to stay in the same position or very close to the same position. This does not make any sense to me. What is causing this behavior?

**Edit 2**

I figured out what is causing the translation of the views but I'm still not sure how to fix it. It seems like if I move the views using `setx()` or `setY()` any time before the animation, then it gets messed up. This is because the animation is still using the original location of the view, not the new one. So when it translates the view, it is being translated toward the original location. How can I make the `ScaleAnimation` use the correct coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

try to use pivotXType and pivotYType is `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF`.

Comment: Setting both to `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF` and both pivot values to `0.5f` did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

try to use pivotXType and pivotYType is `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF`.

In my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    tools:context="com.sonnv1368.animationscale.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        animationImageView();
    }

    private void animationImageView() {
        if (imageView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            final ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(
                    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            scaleAnimation.setDuration(5000);
            imageView.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
        }
    }
}
```

It is working, it will scale at center of imageview.